# How to Redirct QProcess StandardOutput

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qprocess

I am using two instances of `QProcess`. In some portions of my code I need `process1` to redirect its output to `process2`.
By following Qt documentation I can use `QProcess.setStandardOutput()`, which is great. But, later on I have to disable this in code.
How do I redirect its output to the default behavior (stdout)? I have tried `process1 = QProcess()`, but it did not work.

```
process1 = QProcess()
process2 = QProcess()
process1.setStandardOutputProcess(process2)
process1.start("command1")
process2.start("command2")
```

`process1.setStandardOutputProcess(QProcess())`
works but is that the correct way of redistricting? Or am I creating a new "uneccessry" object?

Comment: With your comment to my answer (which I did not test) I think that it is not possible to disable it when the processes are running (perhaps it is a bug or an expected but not documented behavior). Given this, the workaround that you indicate I think is the most appropriate solution. I recommend you report it. Perhaps the Qt developers should verify that the QProcess being redirected to is not a nullptr.

Comment: @eyllanesc Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reporting this as a bug on [Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1522) bug tracker.

I have received the following reply:

> That is a limitation of Qt,
> `QProcess::setStandardOutputProcess(Qprocess *destination)` expects a
> non-null pointer; it is not meant to be changed at runtime.

My workaround to this issue was to use `process1.setStandardOutputProcess(QProcess())`.

**EDIT**
I asked if there is a workaround and received the following reply

> Is there a recommended workaround?

He replied

> No. It is not designed to allow for a change of device
> (since there are most likely I/O buffers involved).
> Similarly, when doing something like

```
ls -l | fgrep "bla"
```

> in the shell, there is no way the change the 2nd process in
> mid-flight, either.